# RxJava2 - interval and schedulers

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Let's say I have an interval, and that I've given it a computationScheduler. Like this:

```
Observable
    .interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, computationScheduler)
    .flatMap { ... }
```

Then, will everything that happens in flatmap {...} also be scheduled on a computation thread?

In the sources for Observable.interval(long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler), it says:

```
 * @param scheduler
 * the Scheduler on which the waiting happens and items are emitted
```

As a beginner to RxJava, I'm having a hard time understanding this comment. I understand that the interval timer/waiting logic occurs on the computation thread. But, does the last part, about items being emitted, also mean that the emitted items will be *consumed* on the same thread? Or is an observeOn required for that? Like this:

```
Observable
    .interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, computationScheduler)
    .observeOn(computationScheduler)
    .flatMap { ... }
```

Would that observeOn be necessary if I want the emits to be processed on the computation thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple to verify: just print the current thread to see on which thread the operator is executed:

```java
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    .flatMap(e -> {
        System.out.println("on flatmap: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return Observable.just(e).map(x -> "--> " + x);
    })
    .subscribe(s -> {
        System.out.println("on subscribe: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(s);
    });
```

This will always print :

```
on subscribe: main
--> 1
on flatmap: main
on subscribe: main
--> 2
on flatmap: main
on subscribe: main
--> 3
on flatmap: main
on subscribe: main
--> 4
on flatmap: main
on subscribe: main
--> 5
on flatmap: main
on subscribe: main
--> 6
on flatmap: main
on subscribe: main
--> 7
on flatmap: main
on subscribe: main
--> 8
on flatmap: main
on subscribe: main
--> 9
```

Processed sequentially because all happen in a single thread -> `main`.

`observeOn` will change the downstream execution thread :

```java
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .flatMap(e -> {
         System.out.println("on flatmap: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
         return Observable.just(e).map(x -> "--> " + x);
     })
     .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .subscribe(s -> {
         System.out.println("on subscribe: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
         System.out.println(s);
      });
```

The result this time will be different for each execution but `flatmap` and `subscribe` will be processed in diffrent threads:

```
on flatmap: RxComputationThreadPool-1
on subscribe: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
```

`interval` will act as `observeOn` and change the downstream execution thread (scheduler):

```java
Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.computation())
    .flatMap(e -> {
        System.out.println("on flatmap: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return Observable.just(e).map(x -> "--> " + x);
    })
    .subscribe(s -> {
        System.out.println("on subscribe: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(s);
    });
```

This time the execution is sequential inside one thread of computation scheduler:

```
on flatmap: RxComputationThreadPool-1
on subscribe: RxComputationThreadPool-1
--> 0
on flatmap: RxComputationThreadPool-1
on subscribe: RxComputationThreadPool-1
--> 1
on flatmap: RxComputationThreadPool-1
on subscribe: RxComputationThreadPool-1
--> 2
on flatmap: RxComputationThreadPool-1
on subscribe: RxComputationThreadPool-1
--> 3
...
```

**`interval` will by default use the computation scheduler, you don't need to pass it as an argument and `observeOn` is not needed**